# MS Access subform resizing

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 forms; a parent form (`frmResults`) and a sub form located within the parent form (`frmResultsSub`). The sub displays the search results from a query, and will have horizontal and vertical scrollbars depending on the number of fields and records returned.

To give the user a better viewing experience of the results subform, I have been playing about with tyring to implement a method to automatically resize the subform (increasing the number of fields and records displayed) as the user drags in/out the parent form, and allowing them access to the sub's scrollbars at all times.

On the parent's Resize event I have the following...

```
Me.Section(0).Height = Me.InsideHeight

Me.frmResultsSub.Width = Me.WindowWidth -  700

If Me.WindowHeight > 2650 Then
    Me.frmResultsSub.Height = Me.WindowHeight - 1850
End If
```

I have the parent form's scrollbars switched off - the only scrollbars present are those of the subform, and I have additional space at the parent top for extra info and a couple of cmd buttons.

To an extent, this works well...through trial and error (with 2 of the 3 numeric values above) there is a small border around the subform.

**Problem:**
I've had to place a minimal subform height of 2650 since Access will error out otherwise.

However, if the parent form is dragged too large Access still errors with a "Run-time error '2100'  the control or subform is too large for this location"

Instead of adding more minimum and maximum subform values (if that would work), is there a better way to implement a subform resize, preferably also allowing for the parent form's min/max buttons to work. I have a few additional forms that would benefit with similar resizing.

Thanks for any help.

[Access 2003 compliance required]

**Edit:** I've added `Me.Section(0).Height = Me.InsideHeight` to try to adjust for the form's Detail section, but Access still throws the same error (I don't see a .Width equivalent for the Detail section)

**Edit2:** this problem seems identical to that seen at http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/maximum-width-if-a-subform-in-access-2k.2601154/  unfortunately, no answer was provided.

I've changed to using `Me.InsideWidth` / `InsideHeight` but still have Access error out when the subform tries to get wider that around 31560. Interestingly, `Me.Width` will only grow to about 31560 before it changes to a negative value...`Me.InsideWidth` continues to grow as a positive number as the window stretches wider. By only having a .Width property for the subform I wonder if this is the issue (the subform will change to a negative value at the same point, throwing the resize off)

Comment: Maximum form width is (and has always been) 22 inch = 55.87 cm. With 1440 Twips per inch that's 31680. No form can be wider than that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, Andre.

Comment: This is why forms have scroll bars.